# How to make Things interact, when a server is online or offline

Tags: c#, ping

So im very new to c# and someone asked me to make him a Windows Forms Application, in which you were able to see, if their Servers are online or offline. He wanted me to make an aquarium, in which the fishes(Servers) swim, while they are online and when they are offline, they just lay on the surface of the water. But i dont know, who to include the fishes into my code:

```
 private static bool IsServer1Up(string hostName)
        {
            bool retVal = false;
            try
            {
                Ping pingSender = new Ping();
                PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
                options.DontFragment = true;
                string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                int timeout = 120;

                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(hostName, timeout, buffer, options);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    retVal = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retVal = false;

            }
            return retVal;
        }
```

This was what i thought of. If you could hlp me that would be very great

PS: Sorry if I missspelled something or there were many grammar mistakes, Im 11 years old and from Germany :D

Comment: This question is to broad. But here some hints what you have to  do:

1) Learn how to draw things. Try to create an application where you draw fishes - you could add a panel into your window and google for something like "c# winforms how to draw image on panel"

2) You need to learn how you could trigger some events regulary and how to use timers, again, google is your friend. Then you can check the servers in a time interval and change what you drawed

Comment: @SirBirne I already have some drawn fishes, but ist not about the fish, ist about where i Need to add the "Image of the Server" in my code

Comment: You can create something like a list of servers. Than you draw a fish in your drawing function for each server -> as stated in my first comment try to use a timer to check the server state regulary and redraw your fishes according to your results.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try that

Answer (score 1):

I try to get you on the right way.

First you need a class representing your servers. This could look something like that:

```
class Server
{
     public string HostName { get; private set; }
     public bool IsOnline { get; private set; }

     public Server(string hostName)
     {
        HostName = hostName;
     }

     public bool CheckState()
     {
        IsOnline = YourLogicForChecking(HostName);
        return IsOnline;
     }
}
```

In your Application you need to initialze a Collection of all your servers. Assuming that you know how to draw your fishes you can than implement a method wich does something like that.

```
public void DrawFish(Server s)
{
   /* your drawing logic, if server is offline the fish is dead, else it is alive */
}
```

Then you should use a timer which updates the state of your servers and calls the drawing function for each server. Here is an example what your Form could look like.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Servers = LoadAllServers();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Start();

    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

 }

 public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      foreach(var s in Servers)
      {
         s.CheckState();
         DrawFish(s);
      }
 }
```

Comment: No problem, happy programming :)